# Class 'PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings' not found in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 1348

Tags: php, magento

After upgraded to PHP 7, my website magento print order using PhpWord library not working.

I have this error:

> Cannot use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\String as String because 'String' is a special class name in /home/.../vendor/phpoffice/phpword/src/PhpWord/Style/Paragraph.php

Then I using lastest PhpOffice/PhpWord and PhpOffice/Common but it's showing next error:

> Fatal error: Class 'PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings' not found in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 1348

Can you help me solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1:
I renamed class String to Stringg in entire phpword library and this works for me with php7 and older version of php too..

Solution 2:
or one can use by giving alias to string class like

```
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\String as POString;
```

And now use POString as mentioned below.

```
public function setText($text)
{
$this->text = POString::toUTF8($text);
return $this;
}
```

This can also works fine

Answer (score -1):

**Solution:**

Rename the file `phpoffice/phpword/src/PhpWord/Shared/String.php` into `phpoffice/phpword/src/PhpWord/Shared/StringHelper.php`. Use a texteditor which has a search and replace feature over multiple files or a command shell tool like `find` or `sed` in order to search for lines `use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\String;` and replace each by a line `use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\StringHelper;` . This means that the whole word `String` must be replaced by `StringHelper` on all places in all the PHP files. Search also for `String::` and replace it by 'StringHelper::` .

**Explanation:**

The class `String` seems to be reserved by PHP and not even a namespace is allowed. Solution: Use the class name `StringHelper` instead of it.

**Linux Shell:**

```
find . -name '*.php'  -exec grep -nw String {} \; -ls
```

This will list you all the files and the line numbers where you must make the replacements.